# Button color is changing when pressed but when i go for next iteration that button color is not going to default background color

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I'm very new to the android app development. Currently I'm doing simple android quiz app with 10 questions.

My default options button color is white. When user is answered a question out of three options, i want to show them the selected option by changing the option button color( by using setBackground color in setOnClickListener method).

But my problem is, My first question selected option color is coming to second question also without selecting answer. I dont know how to cancel the background color on each iteration.

Thanks in Advance!!!

```
    Option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            selected_option = 0;
            question_id = 1;
            Option1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Yellow);
            updateSelectedAnswer(selected_option, question_id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of doing that manually in the code, you should use a StateListDrawable.

Answer (score 3):

We can define [ColorStateList resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource).

You can do it using  as below (feel free to change color according to your need):

Create a file in `res/color/button_background_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="@android:color/red" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="@android:color/blue" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:color="@android:color/green" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/yellow" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Then, use it as below:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@color/button_background_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are showing next question before that change the color of button like as below code...
Option1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);